# Processing user input to dynamic webpage

Tags: php, html

My webpage has a problem I want to take the user input (text/select values and pictures) and then process them into a new HTML page which has the title same as in the I already have a DragnDrop area for pictures which pushes the picture to /uploads

All to happen when user presses submit button.

```
<div id="container">

<div id="content-left">
<h1>Mbushi të dhënat për kontakt</h1>
<form>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
  <label for="male">Sell</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Buy</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="female" value="female"><br><br>
  g
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
    </div>

<div id="dropbox">
        <span class="message">Zhvendosni fotot këtu për ti ngarkuar.<br><i>Limiti 1mb për foto.</i></span>
</div>
```

I'm kind of new to PHP and would like how could I process that to a new-made web page with pre-defined styles of each.

I have everything set up as a .php website. I only miss this to process the user input.

Comment: Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/). Look-up PHP `$_POST` and `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="WRITE_THE_PATH_TO_FILE_HERE.php" method="GET">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
  <label for="male">Sell</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Buy</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="female" value="female"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in PHP to check what was passed to the page

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET) ;

if (isset($_GET['title'], $_GET['option'])){
  echo "Title and option have been submitted" ;
}

?>
```

Comment: Does that mean that I only can create one dynamic page from this input ?

Comment: You can pass the data to any page. If you want to pass them to the same page use `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>" method="GET">`

Comment: But I want to  make it so when I $_GET the title to make it a new .html page from title ?
each time a new page is created from the _GET title.
A new .html page